# Relationships of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get all relationships for model. IE, I've got `User` model:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => 'author'
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :role
end
```

So how can I know which relationships `User` model has got? And foreign_keys if they are presented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations.each do |assoc|
  puts "#{assoc.macro} #{assoc.name}"
end
```

Outputs:

```
has_many messages
has_many posts
belongs_to role
```

The `reflect_on_all_associations` method return an array of [MacroReflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/MacroReflection.html) objects.  They support other methods as well, for querying the options hash of each association and other useful stuff.