# Listing the names of associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Is there a class method for Article with which I can retrieve a list of associations? I know by looking at the model's code that Article is associated to Comment and Category. But is there a method to get these associations programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationships of model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178587/relationships-of-model)

Comment: Yup I agree. Sorry I couldn't find that one before.

Comment: @Mike Lewis answer is even better :)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You want [ActiveRecord::Reflection::ClassMethods#reflect_on_all_associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations)

So it would be:

```
 Article.reflect_on_all_associations
```

And you can pass in an optional parameter to narrow the search down, so:

```
 Article.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)

 Article.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)
```

Keep in mind that if you want the list of all the names of the models you can do something like:

```
Article.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name)
```

This will return a list of all the model names that belong to `Article`.

Comment: This is not totally accurate. That returns the name of the associations, not the name of the models.

Comment: Names of models are very similar: `Article.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:class_name)`

Comment: how you get the names that are associated via `has_rich_text` and `has_many_attached`?

Comment: I have simply been using `reflections` with `keys` as needed.